# when does occur this crash report?

Tags: realbasic

I got this crash report from my app, and I can't reproduce it as I don't know when it happens and how can happen.
Someone can tell me what sees from this report?

Code:

```
Error Name: NilObjectException
Error Number: 0
Error Message:
Stack Trace:
RaiseNilObjectException
ConScheduler.ConScheduler.StyleGrid1_DropObject%%o<ConScheduler.ConScheduler>o<DragItem>i4
_Z17UpdateMouseCursorv
Delegate.Invoke%%
Application._CallFunctionWithExceptionHandling%%o<Application>p
_Z33CallFunctionWithExceptionHandlingPFvvE
_Z8mainloopv
RuntimeRun
REALbasic._RuntimeRun
_Main
% main
```

Regards,
Pentium10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the text, you might want to check out your usage of the Einhugur StyleGrid.  It appears the NilObjectException came from there.